# Окраска полигонов карт из конструктора карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Импортирую на сайт карту из конструктора.

В конструкторе полигоны окрашены - https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3A6da06a99ea6ad8877b2abe6a5e77cd637c035d7a6ff97d85ee6b711d018e33bb&source=constructorLink

Импортирую на сайт кодом из Песочницы - https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_geojson

В общем, работает, но цвета не цепляются, все регионы показываются одинаковым цветом. Как можно раскрасить полигоны на импортируемой карте?

Comment: Вам надо править код примера под свой файл - посмотрите внимательно, там цвета заданы в других полях json'а, чем в файле из Конструктора

Comment: Задача - ничего не  править. Сделать импорт из конструктора, и не залезая в него руками, сразу показать результат на сайте. Это возможно?

Comment: Да, конечно, править надо не файл, а код, который визуализирует данные.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, разобрался, если кто будет также удивляться, вот решение (доработка метода из примера):

```js
function onZonesLoad(json) {

        json.features.forEach(function (obj) {

            if (typeof(obj.options) === 'undefined' && typeof(obj.properties) !== 'undefined') {

                obj.options = {};

                if (obj.properties.fill) {
                    obj.options.fillColor = obj.properties.fill + "60";
                }

                if (obj.properties.stroke) {
                    obj.options.strokeColor = obj.properties.stroke + "60";
                }
            }

        });


        var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();

        // Adding JSON object descriptions to the object manager.
        objectManager.add(json);
        // Adding objects to the map.
        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    }
```